How to integrate TradingView Widget with Vue.js
I’m trying to integrate TradingView ticker tape widget into my Vue.js application, but I’m having trouble getting it to display correctly. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Complete Page Code: Dashboard.template
Vue.js Single File Component (SFC) or a similar template-based structure.
Please check ticker start section.
<app-layout>
    <Head>
        <title>{{ $t('CoinsPay Crypto Exchange Ultimate') }}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <!-- Ticker Script loaded globally in app.blade.php -->
    </Head>
    <!-- head start -->
    <section class="head noselect">
        <div class="head-row">

            <div class="head-title">
                <h1>{{ $t('The Most') }}
                    <span class="typer typer-text" id="typer-main" :data-words="$t('Trusted') +','+ $t('Secure') +','+ $t('Fast') +','+ $t('Reliable')" data-delay="100" data-deleteDelay="1000"></span>
                    <span class="cursor typer-cursor" data-owner="typer-main"></span>
                    <br>{{ $t('Cryptocurrency Exchange.') }}
                </h1>
                <p>{{ $t('Get started with the easiest and most secure platform to buy, sell, trade, and earn cryptocurrencies.') }}</p>
                <Link :href="route('markets')">{{ $t('Get Access') }}</Link>
            </div>

            <div v-if="articles && articles.data" class="head-carousel">
                <Link as="div" :href="route('articles')" class="cursor-pointer text-right pr-3 home-news-link">{{ $t('All news &amp; announcements')}} &rarr;</Link>
                <hooper :settings="hooperSettings">
                    <slide v-for="article in articles.data">
                            <div @click.stop="setArticle(article)" class="cursor-pointer head-carousel__item">
                                <img :src="article.thumbnail">
                            </div>
                    </slide>
                </hooper>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- head end -->
    
    <!-- ticker start -->
    <section class="head ticker-simple">
        <div class="ticker-row" style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 1.5rem 0; border-top: 1px solid #ffffff33; border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff33; width: 100%;">
            <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
            <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
                <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                new TradingView.widget({
                    "symbols": [
                        {"proName": "FOREXCOM:SPXUSD", "title": "S&P 500 Index"},
                        {"proName": "FOREXCOM:NSXUSD", "title": "US 100 Cash CFD"},
                        {"proName": "FX_IDC:EURUSD", "title": "EUR to USD"},
                        {"proName": "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD", "title": "Bitcoin"},
                        {"proName": "BITSTAMP:ETHUSD", "title": "Ethereum"}
                    ],
                    "showSymbolLogo": true,
                    "isTransparent": true,
                    "displayMode": "adaptive",
                    "colorTheme": "dark",
                    "locale": "en"
                });
                </script>
            </div>
            <!-- TradingView Widget END -->
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- ticker end -->

</app-layout>

please help me to resolve this issue.
I’ve tested that the script URL is correct and loading in the browser's network tab. I placed this script under the <head> section in app.blade.php
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js" async></script>
please check my app.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <meta name="site-language" content="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ url('/fav.png') }}" sizes="42x42">

    @role('admin')
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('alternative/css/app.css?v=' . config('app.user_assets_hash')) }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('alternative/css/protected-file-3HnJAidsKJ1.css?v=' . config('app.user_assets_hash')) }}">
    @else

        @if($mobileApp)
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('dependencies/css/app.css?v=' . config('app.user_assets_hash')) }}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('dependencies/css/mobile.css?v=' . config('app.user_assets_hash')) }}">
        @else
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('frontend/css/app.css?v=' . config('app.user_assets_hash')) }}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('frontend/css/site.css?v=' . config('app.user_assets_hash')) }}">
        @endif
    @endrole

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        @php
            $path = resource_path("/lang/". app()->getLocale() .".json");
            $translations = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", file_get_contents($path));
        @endphp
        window.LANGUAGE = "{{ app()->getLocale() }}";
        window.TRANSLATIONS = {!! json_encode($translations); !!}
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js" async></script>

    @if(config('app.analytics'))
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={{ config('app.analytics') }}"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', '{{ config('app.analytics') }}');
    </script>
    @endif
</head>

@if($mobileApp)
<body id="body" class="dark" style="background-color:#1d2234;">
@else
<body id="body" class="{{ $themeMode }}">
@endif
@inertia
</body>

@role('admin')
    <script src="{{ url('js/type.js?v=' . config('app.user_assets_hash')) }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ url('alternative/js/protected-file-3HnJAidsKJ1.js?v=' . config('app.user_assets_hash')) }}" defer></script>
@else

    @if($mobileApp)
        <script src="{{ url('dependencies/js/mobile.js?v=' . config('app.user_assets_hash')) }}" defer></script>
    @else
        <script src="{{ url('js/type.js?v=' . config('app.user_assets_hash')) }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ url('frontend/js/app.js?v=' . config('app.user_assets_hash')) }}" defer></script>
    @endif

@endrole
</html>

I've this error message in my browser console.
Widget settings parse error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
Invalid settings provided, fall back to defaults


" but I’m having trouble getting it to display correctly" - please, be more specific. Is it not displayed at all? You can't use 
Thank you for your response. Yes, you are right; it is not displayed at all. I’m trying to add a script tag directly in the Vue.js template file, and I think it isn’t supported in the same way it is in plain HTML. Please check the updated code in my question and let me know if it will work. @EstusFlask

You are right - embedding <script> tags in Vue templates is not supported. You need to create it dynamically, like const tag = document.createElement('script'); and then set tag.src and any other attributes that you need, e.g. tag.async = true. You should also use a unique tag.id and check document.getElementById() before doing document.createElement() to avoid multiple duplicates of the script which will probably interfere with each other.

@ianasystems It looks ok to me. That's what the lib I mentioned roughly does. Does this work as intended?

Please check now. I've updated more details to understand and resolve this issue. @EstusFlask

@ianasystems The widget tries to parse the contents of script tag as JSON, that's the way custom config is provided to it, see its docs. The error likely doesn't affect how it works. If you don't need custom config and don't want to see an error, provide empty JSON object, <script ... async>{}</script>. If you want it to be integrated into Vue app then you need to take care of this additionally. There's https://github.com/ehsan-shv/vue-tradingviewWidgets that already does this
